# Advanced custom fields - pulling data in from another page

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

Hello I am using advanced custom fields and I am trying to pull data from multiple pages and display it on another

I set up a relationship field called "data", and then on page X where the relationship field is displayed I have chosen page Y where I want to pull the data from

```
<?php if( get_field('data') ): ?>
     <?php the_field('special_offer'); ?> <!--// get content from page Y -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

I can't get this to work though and Im presuming the above is wrong, does anyone know how I could do this please?

Hopefully I have explained it clearly

Cheers

```
<?php if( $related_pages = get_field( 'special_offer_relationship' ) ): ?>

    <?php foreach( $related_pages as $page ): ?>
        <?php echo get_the_title( $page->ID ); ?>
        <?php echo get_the_excerpt( $page->ID ); ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [relationship field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/relationship/) returns an array of post objects. Each post object contains the ID of the related post. The ACF [field functions](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/the_field/) accept a second parameter, which is the post ID you want to retrieve data from, if it is not the current post.

```
if( $related_pages = get_field( 'data' ) ):
    foreach( $related_pages as $page ):
        the_field( 'special_offer', $page->ID );
    endforeach;
endif;
```

All of this is from the [ACF documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/), which is pretty thorough with many examples.

### EDIT

If you want to use template tags that require the global `$post` var, you have to use [setup_postdata()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) to populate it with the post's data. Note that `get_the_excerpt` does not accept a post ID like `get_the_title` does.

```
if( $related_pages = get_field( 'data' ) ):
    foreach( $related_pages as $post ): // you must use $post for this to work
        setup_postdata( $post );
        the_title();
        the_excerpt();
    endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata(); // restore global $post for outer loop
endif;
```

Comment: Sorry on the late reply and thanks a lot for the reply!

For some reason get_the_excerpt, or content is just getting the content from the page you are on, I dont suppose you know of what  might be causing this or if I am doing something wrong? (I have updated the op)

Strangely enough it gets the title fine but not the content :S

Comment: see edit above.